# Deserializing more complex JSON with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: json, serialization

I have a JSON response from Facebook Graph API, that looks like this:

```
    {
  "name": "XXXXXX YYYYYYY", 
  "username": "XXXXXX.YYYYYYY", 
  "email": "XXXXXXYYYYYYY@gmail.com", 
  "location": {
    "id": "110507998976900", 
    "name": "Someplace, Somestate"
  }, 
  "work": [
    {
      "employer": {
        "id": "4647647894784698", 
        "name": "Some Employer"
      }, 
      "location": {
        "id": "7489468976968988", 
        "name": "Someplace, Somestate"
      }, 
      "position": {
        "id": "4876498697859795", 
        "name": "Boss"
      }, 
      "start_date": "0000-00"
    }
  ], 
  "id": "1895789769789679", 
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "url": "https://fbcdn-aaaaaaa.net/aaaaaaaa/458768_484784776868_4875876876_q.jpg", 
      "is_silhouette": false
    }
  }
```

I inherited code that deserializes the response, but I added the more complex fields like location, work and picture into the request, and now the JSON deserializer throws an error.

I have a wrapper class that uses DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(), and a data contract class that looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
    public class FacebookMe
    {        
        private string fbId;
        [DataMember]
        public string id
        {
            get { return fbId; }
            set { fbId = value; }
            } 
...
```

I tried adding the 'work' field first as a string, (that's when the errors started) then as a Dictionary. So far I've had no luck and I'm running out of ideas.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I have since advanced a bit. I created classes within classes to mimic the structure of the JSON notation:

```
 [DataContract]
        public class Work
        {
            [DataContract]
        public class Employer
        {
            private string fbEmployerName;
            [DataMember]
            public string name
            {
                get { return fbEmployerName; }
                set { fbEmployerName = value; }
            }
        }

        private Employer fbEmployer;
        [DataMember]
        public Employer employer
        {
            get { return fbEmployer; }
            set { fbEmployer = value; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class Position
        {
            private string fbPositionName;
            [DataMember]
            public string name
            {
                get { return fbPositionName; }
                set { fbPositionName = value; }
            }
        }

        private Position fbPosition;
        [DataMember]
        public Position position
        {
            get { return fbPosition; }
            set { fbPosition = value; }
        }
    }

    private Work fbWork;
    [DataMember]
    public Work work
    {
        get { return fbWork; }
        set { fbWork = value; }
    }

[DataContract]
        public class Picture
        {
            [DataContract]
            public class Data
            {
                private string fbPictureUrl;
                [DataMember]
                public string url
                {
                    get { return fbPictureUrl; }
                    set { fbPictureUrl = value; }
                }

                private bool fbPictureIsSilhouette;
                [DataMember]
                public bool is_silhouette
                {
                    get { return fbPictureIsSilhouette; }
                    set { fbPictureIsSilhouette = value; }
                }

            }

            private Data fbPictureData;
            [DataMember]
            public Data data
            {
                get { return fbPictureData; }
                set { fbPictureData = value; }
            }
        }

        private Picture fbPicture;
        [DataMember]
        public Picture picture
        {
            get { return fbPicture; }
            set { fbPicture = value; }
        }


    }
```

This results in filling in all the fields properly (and the deserialization error is gone) Except for the "work" element. "work" gets filled with an object, that has fields "employer" and "position", which are both null. "work" has the same level of nested data as "picture", and "picture" works just fine. I handled them both the same way. Yet one works and the other does not.
They only difference I could spot is in the original JSON:

```
work [ {...} ]
picture {...}
```

"work" has those extra brackets. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: which error ? and show more code on DataContract.

Comment: some sort of serialization error. I got rid of that already. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the brackets stand for an array. in this case it's an array of "work" objects, namely one "work" object. There's an array because you could have had more employers, so more "work" objects.
The solution was to set up the data contract class to expect an array of "work" items.

```
private Work[] fbWork;
        [DataMember]
        public Work[] work
        {
            get { return fbWork; }
            set { fbWork = value; }
        }
```